# How to add new item into srt file

Tags: javascript, srt

This is start of a `srt` file:

```
0  
00:00:07,000 --> 00:01:00,000  
lorem ipsum...  // this line doesn't work  

1  
00:01:02,960 --> 00:01:05,800  
lorem ipsum...  

2  
00:01:05,840 --> 00:01:08,960  
lorem ipsum...
```

The first line doesn't work, I suppose because of`0` as the ordinal.
I need a way, javascript way if possible, to correctly change all ordinal numbers at once, not one by one (over 1000 lines), starting with `1` and not with `0`.

I was searching for various online solutions, without success.

Comment: So you want to change a file with JavaScript? Unless you use node I don't think you can.

Comment: @putvande, do you mean `node.js` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an html file with a textarea, load it in your browser and copy 
the contents of the .srt file in. Use the following javascript to convert the textarea's text:

```
var numberRegex = /^\d\s*$/;

var originalLines = text.split('\n');
var lines = [];
for (var index = 0; index != originalLines.length; ++index)
{
    var orig = originalLines[index];
    var match = numberRegex.exec(orig);
    lines.push(match ? parseInt(orig) + 1 : orig);
}
```

Then the converted text you want is provided by:

```
lines.join('\n')
```